# HTML 5 input type="number" element for floating point numbers on Chrome

Tags: html, validation, google-chrome, html-input

I need to have users enter floating point numbers, so I use the following element:

```
<input type="number" name="my_number" placeholder="Enter number"/>
```

Works great on Firefox, but Chrome complains that the number is not an integer when I try to enter a decimal. That's a problem for my case. If I enter a `step` attribute, then Chrome allows the floating point number:

```
<input type="number" name="my_number" placeholder="Enter number" step="0.1"/>
```

But then the problem is 0.15 can't be entered... The `step` doesn't appear to suit my needs. The [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) mentions floating-point numbers throughout the attributes of `input type="number"`.

How do I get Chrome to accept floating point numbers without the `step` attribute?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try `<input type="number" step="any" />`

It won't have validation problems and the arrows will have step of "1"

> Constraint validation: When the element has an allowed value step, and
>   the result of applying the algorithm to convert a string to a number
>   to the string given by the element's value is a number, and that
>   number subtracted from the step base is not an integral multiple of
>   the allowed value step, the element is suffering from a step mismatch.
>
> The following range control only accepts values in the range 0..1, and
>   allows 256 steps in that range:
>
> `<input name=opacity type=range min=0 max=1 step=0.00392156863>`
>
> The
>   following control allows any time in the day to be selected, with any
>   accuracy (e.g. thousandth-of-a-second accuracy or more):
>
> `<input name=favtime type=time step=any>`
>
> Normally, time controls are
>   limited to an accuracy of one minute.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-step

Comment: works great! Is this part of the spec or just a strange workaround?

Comment: This works okay in Chrome but not in Firefox 31 ESR or Firefox 34. I had to resort to input="text" to get what I wanted. Firefox and HTML5 really need to get their act together.

Comment: One problem I ran into, even on Chrome is that "e" or "e.e" is can be typed into the input (because e is a number) but in Angular the value ends up as "undefined".

Answer (score 54):

Try `<input type="number" step="0.01" />` if you are targeting 2 decimal places :-).

Comment: You deserve the point, the easiest solution and I had to search it several getting wrong almost all of them...Thx

Answer (score 4):

Note: If you're using AngularJS, then in addition to changing the step value, you may have to set `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur change'}"` on the html input.

The reason for this is in order to have the validators run less often, as they are preventing the user from entering a decimal point.  This way, the user can type in a decimal point and the validators go into effect after the user blurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<input onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && 
                          event.charCode <= 57 || 
                          event.charCode == 46'>
```

Comment: && !isNaN(this.value) perhaps or this.value.split('.').length==1