# Angular, How can I show 10 as 10.00

Tags: javascript, angularjs, math, numbers, rounding

I have a textbox and I want to show the value the user enters with 2 decimals,
ex. if user entered 10, then I will show 10.00 in the text box.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control"/>
```

It's simple like this, I tried to use watch but am not sure about the method that am going to use in order to reach the required.

Do we have anyway to use currency filter inside a textbox input ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654678/html-5-input-type-number-element-for-floating-point-numbers-on-chrome

Comment: you might want to create a directive that works with ng-model.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" ...>
```

The `step` attribute is actually for the amount of increment/decrement by `up` and `down` buttons but it also happens to set the resolution of the number to a certain number of digits after the decimal in floating point numbers.

Comment: I tried to apply it, but it's not showing the number I am adding as a fixed number, when I enter 10 I want it to display as 10.00

Comment: <input type="number" step="0.01" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"/>

Comment: If you wish for it to appear as currency, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963158/html5-form-input-pattern-currency-format

Answer (score 0):

Would a filter work? You might want to work in some kind of delay so that the form lets the user finish typing before converting the number, but this works (minus the delay):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="numFilterExample">
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                angular.module('numFilterExample',[])
            .controller('NumberFilterController', ['$scope','numberFilter',function($scope,numFilter){
                $scope.change = function(){
                    $scope.num = numFilter($scope.num,2);
                };
            }]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="NumberFilterController">
            <input ng-model='num' ng-change="change()" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```