# calculation using decimal number field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a calculation using number fields that have set decimal places.

While the decimals are being displayed properly, the calculation is not running.  Here is my javascript:

```
 function setZeroNumberDecimal(el) {
    el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(0);
};
 function setThreeNumberDecimal(el) {
    el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(3);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".calc").keyup(function(){
      var areasf = +$(".SF").val();
      $("#acre").val(areasf/43560);
});
});
```

And the HTML:

```
  <input type="number" onchange="setZeroNumberDecimal(this)" name="grosslandSF" class="calc SF">
  <input type="number" onchange="setThreeNumberDecimal(this)" name="grosslandacre" disabled="disabled" id="acre">
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34057860/4824627) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22654797/4824627) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19011861/4824627), the `step` might be the issue here

Comment: The decimals weren't the issue.  It was the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inline onchange event you can use [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput) event.

When you change a value like in:

```
$("#acre").val(areasf/43560)
```

this will not [fire](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the corresponding event, so you must do it by yourself:

```
$("#acre").val(areasf/43560).trigger('input');
```

The snippet:

```js
function setZeroNumberDecimal(el) {
    el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(0);
};
function setThreeNumberDecimal(el) {
    el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(3);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".calc").keyup(function(){
        var areasf = +$(".SF").val();
        $("#acre").val(areasf/43560).trigger('input');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <input type="number" oninput="setZeroNumberDecimal(this)" name="grosslandSF" class="calc SF">
    <input type="number" oninput="setThreeNumberDecimal(this)" name="grosslandacre" disabled="disabled" id="acre">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, the calc is running and sticking to 3 decimals.  However, if you put in 43560, the result is 1, whereas it should be 1.000 (it's a land thing with acres, should always result in 3 decimals even if a whole number)

Comment: @MichaelM Indeed, if you input 43560 the result is 1.000. Which browser are you using?

Comment: You are correct.  I forgot to change my onchange to oninput.  Thank you, gaetanoM.  You saved me a huge headache!